# What order? register_taxonomy() register_taxonomy_for_object_type() register_post_type()

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

In what order are these functions supposed to be called?

```
 register_taxonomy( $catname, $cpt  );
 register_taxonomy_for_object_type(  $catname, $cpt);                                                 
 register_post_type( $cpt, $args );//without the taxonomies argument
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order really shouldn't really matter but it's good practice to register things in a hierarchical structure.

```
register_post_type( $cpt, $args );
register_taxonomy( $catname, $cpt );
```

Comment: I think in most scenarios, you dont need "register_taxonomy_for_object_type()" ?

Comment: Correct. `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()` is useful when you want to add an already registered taxonomy to a custom object type. For example, add the default post category taxonomy to your custom post type: `register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', $cpt );`.